# Linq query for two database tables with three columns

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem. I have two tables in my database, both with the same structure. I want to use `Union` in my Linq query to merge both tables together, but I can't merge them with more then one column.

This is my code:

```
var result1 = from t in db.table1 select new { t.FieldOne, t.FieldTwo };            
var result2 = from g in db.table2 select new { g.FieldOne, g.FieldTwo};            
var combinedTable= result1.Union(result2).ToList();
```

But I get an error. If I do this with just one column for each table, it works.

It would be great if someone can help me to do this with two or more columns :)

Comment: Either your fields have different names, or different types.  The solution is to therefore make sure that the fields have the same names, and the same types.  There isn't enough information in your question to determine in what way those two classes differ.

Comment: @Servy - The first Field have the same name in both tables - the second field have different names but the exact datatypes (varchar(255)) - i think this is the error! I will try to fix this and post it here if it works or not

Comment: Ok - this was the error. I renamed the fields in the table and now it works.Thank you for this information!

Answer (score -1):

Your code define 2 anonymous types.

- `result1` is of type `IQueryable<Anonymous1>`
- `result2` is of type `IQueryable<Anonymous2>`

You can't merge collections of different types.

So, what is the solution?

Define a simple intermediate type (like the compiler do when it define anonymous type).

```
class MyResultItem
{
    public string FieldOne { get; set; }
    public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
}

IQueryable<MyResultItem> result1 = from t in db.table1 select new MyResultItem {
    FieldOne = t.FieldOne,
    FieldTwo = t.FieldTwo
};            
IQueryable<MyResultItem> result2 = from g in db.table2 select new MyResultItem {
    FieldOne = g.FieldOne,
    FieldTwo = g.FieldTwo
};            
IEnumerbale<MyResultItem> combinedTable = result1.Union(result2).ToList();
```

As you can see I do not use the keyword `var`. That is because this is not teaching. **Many questions about the use of LINQ are related to the understanding of typing**. `anonymous type` and `var` keyword are very convenient but if you find an compile-time error, **the first thing to do is to rewrite the expression by replacing it by explicit types**.

Comment: There is no problem with using anonymous types here at all.  Anonymous types that have the exact same members with the same name and the same type will be defined as the same type, not separate but identical types, and so the code will work just fine.  The problem with the OP's code is that the fields *aren't* identical for some reason, either due to a different name or a different type.  *That* is the problem that needs to be fixed.